# Problem with AJAX Post request in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a select box and when each item is selected, a ajax request is sent.
but my code does not work. i'm get status 404 and this error is displayed in the console

```
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException", file: "F:\\source\\boiler\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php", line: 179, …
```

my route :

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'BuyCrypto' , 'prefix' => 'crypto'], function() {
          Route::post('/calculateBuyAmount' , [BuyCryptoController::class , 'calculateAmount'])->name('calculate.amount');
        });
```

ajax code :

```
$("select#user_select_crypto").change(function(e) {

    $('#calculat_user_buy').block({
        message: '<i class="icon-spinner4 spinner"></i>',

        overlayCSS: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            opacity: 0.8,
            cursor: 'wait'
        },
        css: {
            border: 0,
            padding: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "panel/crypto/calculateBuyAmount",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

            user_select_crypto: $("input[name=user_select_crypto]").val(),
            user_value_request: $("input[name=user_value_request]").val(),
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(result)
        },
        error: function(result) {

            console.log(result)

        },
    });
});
```

what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because laravel not getting the full URL of your giving route. you have to give the correct route. for this, you can use your named route like below.

```
url: "{{ route('calculate.amount') }}",
```

or in case you are in a javascript file and can't use blade than just give URL with `/` slash. all is going to work. Its happen with a post request.

you can give URL like below

```
url: "/panel/crypto/calculateBuyAmount",
```

**Updated**

Now you facing `methodNotAllowedException`  because now you sending a get request because you are not mentioning in ajax side you are doing a `post` request. by default ajax will send a `get` request. so you need to tell ajax use post method. like that `type: "POST"` like below

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/panel/crypto/calculateBuyAmount",
        dataType: 'json',
        type : 'POST'
        data: {

            user_select_crypto: $("input[name=user_select_crypto]").val(),
            user_value_request: $("input[name=user_value_request]").val(),
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(result)
        },
        error: function(result) {

            console.log(result)

        },
    });
```

Comment: i edited it but now again this error returned : ```Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException```

Comment: because now you sendnig a `get` request beacuse you are not metioning in ajax side you are doing a post. by default ajax will send a get request. so you need to tell ajax use post method. like that `type: "POST",`

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, it is good to use named route as you give your route a name.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('calculate.amount') }}",   // use your name route here
    type : 'POST',   // need to add your request type post 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {

        user_select_crypto: $("input[name=user_select_crypto]").val(),
        user_value_request: $("input[name=user_value_request]").val(),
    },
    success: function(result) {

        console.log(result)
    },
    error: function(result) {

        console.log(result)

    },
});
```

Comment: i edited it  but now again this error returned : ```Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException```

Comment: See my updated answer, You need to add request type POST.